# Makefile compilation warning (libftprintf.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the libr ary define global symbols)

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to compile my Makefile to make library from different directories. The library is successfully compiled but I am facing the following warning

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C ./libft
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.     
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -c srcs/ft*.c libft/ft*.c -I ./includes
ar rcs libftprintf.a srcs/ft*.c libft/ft*.c*****
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Xcod
eDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: archive library: libftprintf.a
 the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the libr
ary define global symbols)
```

Please kindly advise on how to solve this warning. The structure of my directory is as follow:

```
steh@u90z01s01 printf % ls
Makefile includes main.c libft srcs
```

My Makefile is as following

```
NAME  := libftprintf.a
CC    := gcc      
AR    := ar rcc
CFLAGS:= -Wall -Werror -Wextra -c
SRCS   = srcs/ft*.c libft/ft*.c     
INCLUDES = ./includes
OBJ_FILES = $(SRCS:%.c = %.o)     

$(NAME): $(OBJ_FILES)#.fr 
         $(MAKE) -C ./libft
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS) -I $(INCLUDES)
         $(AR) $(NAME) $(OBJ_FILES)

all: $(NAME)

clean:
@echo "Cleaning..."
rm -rf $(NAME) ft*.o

fclean:
rm -rf $(NAME)

re: fclean all

norm:
@norminette $(LIB_FILES)

.PHONY: clean fclean all re norm
```

This is my latest code

```
NAME    := libftprintf.a
CC      := gcc
AR      := ar rcs
CFLAGS  := -Wall -Werror -Wextra -c
SRCS     = ./libft/ft*.c ./srcs/ft*.c
OBJS     = ft*.o
LIBFT     = ./libft
INC      = ./includes


# Colors
GREEN= \033[1;32m
RED= \033[1;31m


all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): 
        @make re -C $(LIBFT)
        @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS) -I $(INC)
        @$(AR) $(NAME) $(OBJS)
        @ranlib $(NAME)
        @echo "$(GREEN)ft_printf compiled!"
```

Comment: It's hard to give a full answer when you haven't shown us the full situation (such as `libft/Makefile`), but the Unix wildcard `*` doesn't work in a Makefile the way you seem to think it does. What do you think the prerequisites of the rule are?

Comment: The `ar` command appears to store C source code in the library, not object files.  The linker won't link source files.  It is legitimate (but eccentric) to store source files.

Comment: I have post my latest code in the questions. I changed my code by changing the OBJS variable and using ranlib. Now the warning seem to disappear. Can please give me some advice. Thank you.